# PyQt QImage cna't copy, crash without error code

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pydicom

I want to show on a QImage and translate to QPixmap, but when I want to manipulate(copy, scaled, or construct by QPixmap) qimage then the process will crash.But If I copy to a small rectangle like(2048, 2048) It was not crash any more.

This arr is numpy ndarray, shape:(3408, 2235) dtype:uint16, maximum value is 65535 and minimum is 0.

I wonder why the process will crash without error code.

How can I fix it?

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from pydicom import dcmread
import numpy as np
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(2048, 2048)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.photo = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.photo.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 2048, 2048))
        self.photo.setText("")
        ds = dcmread('./5F329172_20170623_CR_2_1_1')
        arr = ds.pixel_array
        print("ndarray shape: ", arr.shape, " dtype: ", arr.dtype)
        print("ndarray max: ", np.max(arr), " min: ", np.min(arr))
        qimage = QtGui.QImage(arr, arr.shape[1], arr.shape[0], QtGui.QImage.Format_Grayscale16)
        qimage = qimage.copy()
        # qimage = qimage.copy(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 2048, 2048)) this will not crash
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(qimage)
        self.photo.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.photo.setScaledContents(True)
        self.photo.setObjectName("photo")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
     

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Update:

dicom data: [5F329172_20170623_CR_2_1_1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n10BeZ2ReyvPK5yXRc26eFBL6qnCHmWp/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: share the 5F329172_20170623_CR_2_1_1 file

Comment: @eyllanesc ok I will update it. Thank you.

Comment: @eyllanesc I upadted the file.